# SQL Query to fetch count for Parent-Child data relationship

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a requirement to get count of parent-child relationship.

```
  QuestionID    ParentQuestionID
    207         NULL
    208         NULL
    209         207
    210         208
    211         209
    212         210
```

For example, question id 207 has child id 209 & 209 has child id 211. so totally 207 has two child ids. So i want to return count as 2. How can i do that. Can some one help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
( 
 select QuestionID, ParentQuestionID, 0 as lvl 
 from questiontable
 where QuestionID = 207
 union all
 select q.QuestionID, q.ParentQuestionID, lvl+1 
 from questiontable q
 inner join cte c on c.QuestionID= q.ParentQuestionID
)

select count(*) from cte 
where QuestionID <> 207
```

You can use a parameter instead of hard-coded value 207 to make it dynamic for any `QuestionID`.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/XGXF17511)